# How to change the android default browser default Home URL

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-browser

I am developing an application in which I need a feature like - when I install the app, the home page of the android default browser will be replaced by http://myurl.com . That means I need to change the configuration of android default browser. May be it is related with changing value of `SharedPreference` but I don't know how that can be done.

I know android browser code is open source but at this moment I don't have any idea with android default browser source code. How can I do that when my app will be installed first?

Comment: I'm fairly (although admittedly not absolutely) certain this isn't possible, because apps are sandboxed, so you won't be able to access the browser's private sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ben Williams

```
I'm fairly (although admittedly not absolutely) certain this isn't possible, 
because apps are sandboxed, so you won't be able to access the browser's
private sharedpreferences.
```